# nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 6

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am getting an error when I try to update a record in my database. I believe the error is being cased by trying to accept 6 values in input but when updating the record I am only using 5 of them. I need to use the eventId to update the database record for the specific entry. I do not want to change the eventId and would rather just delete the event. My table is designed in the following order -- eventId, eventTitle, roomId, eventInfo, startDate, endDate. The error I am getting is

> nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for
>   parameter 6

```
public void updateEvent(int eventId, String eventTitle, int roomId, String eventInfo, String startDate, String endDate) {
 String SQL = "UPDATE Event SET eventTitle = ?, roomID = ?, eventInfo = ?, startDate = ?, endDate =? WHERE eventId = ?";
  jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL,eventTitle,roomId,eventInfo,startDate,endDate);
  System.out.println("Updated Event with eventID = " + eventId );
  return;    
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I am using MySQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing eventId here:

```
jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL,eventTitle,roomId,eventInfo,startDate,endDate,eventId);
```

Comment: But if I add the eventId in there will it not update the eventID too when it runs? I just need to update the event information.

Comment: I feel stupid. Yes it works, I thought it would update the eventID. Thank you.